# Is every probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Say I have some arbitrary $N$-dimensional probability distribution $P$.

I'd like to create a deterministic function that accepts a vector of $N$ uniformly distributed numbers and generates an $N$ element vector where the elements of this vector are distributed according to $P$.

Is this always possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $N=1$ then it is always possible.
   Let $$ X\sim F, $$
   there exists $$F^{-1}(u)=\inf \{x\in \mathbb{R}\colon F(x)\ge u\}$$ where $0< u<1$. Thus $$ F^{-1}(U)\sim F$$
   with $U\sim Unif(0,1)$. This method is called inverse transform.
2. If $N>1$. Let $$ X=(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_N)\sim F $$
   where $$F(x_1,\dots,x_N)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\le x_1,\dots, X_N\le x_N).$$
   If $X_1,\dots,X_N$ are independent, then $$F(x_1,\dots,x_N)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\le x_1)\cdots \mathbb{P}(X_N\le x_N)=F_{X_1}(x_1)\cdots F_{X_N}(x_N).$$
   Thus is possible to simulate each $X_i$ by inverse transform method and so
   $$ (F_{X_1}^{-1}(U_1),\dots,F_{X_N}^{-1}(U_N))\sim F$$
   where $U_1,\dots,U_N$ i.i.d. with $U_1\sim Unif(0,1)$.
   If $X_1,\dots,X_N$ are dependent then a procedure that takes this into account is necessary.

Comment: So the sufficiency condition here is that $F$ is invertible?

Comment: Yes, although this is a very strong hypothesis, and in practice difficult to achieve. Also, note that when $N = 1$ we use a generalized inverse, and even this method is not widely used in practice. In practice, Markov Chain Monte Carlo is used to simulate a complex distribution.

Comment: In the one-dimensional case the "probability integral transform" is used quite routinely. It's especially easy to implement in the discrete setting, where there are also alternatives that avoid the need for a binary search lookup (by using some preprocessing).

Comment: An example with dependence is a Markov chain http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/4703-Sigman/4703-07-Notes-MC.pdf